# Is there a way to exclude tag synonyms from searches?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, api

I was looking for single-use tags, and approximately half of our tags on [Travel-SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) (10 pages of them) are actually used once or are synonyms, so this is almost an exercise in futility.

To make it more clear:

Say that we have [foo](/questions/tagged/foo)->[bar](/questions/tagged/bar), i.e. [bar](/questions/tagged/bar) is the main tag, and [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) is the synonym. I want to get [bar](/questions/tagged/bar) in the results or when browsing, but not [foo](/questions/tagged/foo).

Is there a way to exclude the synonym tags when browsing? Alternatively, is there a way to do this from the Stack API? I think we have a person or two here that can work with this (hi Roflcoptr!).

Comment: I don't think the title says it all. You want a) a list of all and only the "main" tags? If you have "a" and "b" as synonyms you only want to exclude one right? Because they are both synonyms of each other. You can't say "big" is a synonym but "large" is not, if you follow me...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible through the UI or through the API. You can do it pretty easily through [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120647/?MaxOccurences=1), which might be the best way if you're just trying to clean-up tags